# word interop solid lines

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, office-interop

I need a paragraph with some bold words, when making this gives me results in three paragraphs and I need all this in one. there any way to accomplish this?

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph para1 = document.Content.Paragraphs.Add();
para1.Range.Text = "Dónde puedo conseguirlo";
para1.Range.Font.Bold = 0;
para1.Range.Font.Size = 11;
para1.Range.Font.Name = "Arial";
para1.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphJustify;
para1.Range.Underline = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdUnderline.wdUnderlineNone;
para1.Format.SpaceAfter = 0; 
para1.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph para8 = document.Content.Paragraphs.Add();
para8.Range.Text = "Lorem Ipsum";
para8.Range.Font.Bold = 1;
para8.Range.Font.Size = 11;
para8.Range.Font.Name = "Arial";
para8.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphJustify;
para8.Range.Underline = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdUnderline.wdUnderlineNone;
para8.Format.SpaceAfter = 0; 
para8.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph para9 = document.Content.Paragraphs.Add();
para9.Range.Text = " Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de textos[enter image description here][1].";
para9.Range.Font.Bold = 0;
para9.Range.Font.Size = 11;
para9.Range.Font.Name = "Arial";
para9.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphJustify;
para9.Range.Underline = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdUnderline.wdUnderlineNone;
para9.Format.SpaceAfter = 0; 
para9.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
```

Comment: have you tried 'para8.Range.Font.Bold = true'?

Comment: para8.Range.Font.Bold  is int not bool

Comment: Use -1 for "true" when the Word interop requires an int instead of a bool.

Comment: Note that your code would be much more efficient if you would define *styles* for the formatting combinations and then apply the style (one step!) instead of repeating each individual formatting command numerous times. That also makes formatting management simpler as any changes can be made in one place (style definition) instead of multiple times throughout your code (or throughout the document).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Range based on the text you want to change to bold. For example in your first paragraph if you want the word "puedo" bolded:

```
string texto = "Dónde puedo conseguirlo";
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph para1 = document.Content.Paragraphs.Add();
para1.Range.Text = texto;
para1.Range.Font.Bold = 0;
para1.Range.Font.Size = 11;
para1.Range.Font.Name = "Arial";
para1.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphJustify;
para1.Range.Underline = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdUnderline.wdUnderlineNone;
para1.Format.SpaceAfter = 0;
/* select the range based on the word "puedo" */
object start = texto.IndexOf("puedo");
object end = texto.IndexOf("puedo") + "puedo".Length;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range rngBold = document.Range(ref start, ref end);
rngBold.Bold = 1; // apply bold
para1.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
```